# Can anyone explain me this code in java servlets ? is this dynamic polymorphism (overridding)? if so how is this possible?

Tags: java, oop, servlets, web-applications

`HttpSession session = request.getSession();`
here HttpSession is a interface, the `request` is an object of interface `HttpServletRequest` which extends `ServletRequest`. How is this instantiation done by calling a method of another interface? I know its a basic question but I'm new to Java. So, can anyone explain me this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#getSession()` is a method, with the return type of `HttpSession`. There is no instantiation here, it simply returns the `session` property of the `HttpServletRequest`.

To elaborate a bit more: `HttpServletRequest` is an interface, which specifies that every implementation of it should have the `#getSession()` method. The actual `HttpServletRequest` implementation (provided by the servlet container) implements (overrides) this method, and that is where the `HttpSession` object is coming from.

For example, Tomcat's own implementation of the interface is `org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest`, source code is [here](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/core/ApplicationHttpRequest.java#L524).

Answer (score 0):

The `getSession()` method of the `request` object returns an object that's class implements the `HttpSession` interface. You are not doing instantiation directly. The point here is that the `getSession()` method somehow has access to an object that implements `HttpSession`, but from the code that you showed you don't know exactly where that comes from. For that you would have to look into the class implementation.